# GHC - No instance for (Monad Ptr)

Tags: haskell

I'm new to haskell and I'm attempting to write my first haskell C library. This is my first time using the Foreign.C module. I'm getting lost in examples and have become stuck. This is what I have come up with so far:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

module Grep where

import GHC.Ptr
import Foreign.C.String
import Data.List (isInfixOf)

grep :: CString -> CString -> CString
grep i s = do
    ii <- peekCString i
    ss <- peekCString s
    g <- newCString (isInfixOf ii ss)
    g 

foreign export ccall grep :: CString -> CString -> CString
```

I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\GGuy\Source\haskell> ghc -c -O grep.hs

grep.hs:11:9:
  No instance for (Monad Ptr)
    arising from a do statement
  Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Monad Ptr)
  In a stmt of a 'do' block: ii <- (peekCString i)
  In the expression:
    do { ii <- (peekCString i);
      ss <- peekCString s;
      g <- newCString (isInfixOf ii ss);
      g }
  In an equation for `grep':
    grep i s
      = do { ii <- (peekCString i);
             ss <- peekCString s;
             g <- newCString (isInfixOf ii ss);
             .... }

grep.hs:11:16:
  Couldn't match expected type `Ptr t0' with actual type `IO String'
  In the return type of a call of `peekCString'
  In a stmt of a 'do' block: ii <- (peekCString i)
  In the expression:
    do { ii <- (peekCString i);
       ss <- peekCString s;
       g <- newCString (isInfixOf ii ss);
       g }
```

Comment: `isInfixOf` gives a `Bool`, not a `String` as `newCString` wants --- what are you trying to do?

Comment: @dave4420 Thanks! Completely missed that. I'm trying to return true if i is in s. Since there is no CBool I'm guessing the definition export would be "CString -> CString -> Bool"...?

Comment: `CString -> CString -> IO Bool`, after the peeking, you'd just ``return $ ii `isInfixOf` ss``.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now that the fix

```
grep :: CString -> CString -> IO Bool
grep i s = do
    ii <- peekCString i
    ss <- peekCString s
    return (isInfixOf ii ss)

foreign export ccall grep :: CString -> CString -> IO Bool
```

is clarified, let us find out how the error messages come to be:

```
grep :: CString -> CString -> CString
grep i s = do
    ii <- peekCString i
    ss <- peekCString s
    g <- newCString (isInfixOf ii ss)
    g
```

The declared result type of `grep` is `CString`, which is a type synonym for `Ptr CChar`. The right hand side of the definition is a do-block (with more than one statement), so the result type must have the form `m a` for some `Monad m` and some type `a`.

The declared result type `Ptr CChar` matches the form `m a` - with `m = Ptr, a = CChar` - and so what remains is to find/verify the `Monad` instance of the type constructor `Ptr`. There is none in scope, hence

```
grep.hs:11:9:
  No instance for (Monad Ptr)              -- quite
    arising from a do statement            -- right
  Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Monad Ptr)    -- Umm, no, not really
```

the first reported error.

The second error comes from analysing the contents of the do-block. The compiler could have stopped type-checking upon encountering the first error, but didn't. Now the further type checking continues under the assumption that `Ptr` were a `Monad`. So in that do-block, every expression on the right of a `<-` (which, after desugaring becomes the first argument of a `(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> mb) -> m b`), must have type `Ptr sometype`. But `peekCString :: CString -> IO String`, thus

```
grep.hs:11:16:
  Couldn't match expected type `Ptr t0' with actual type `IO String'
  In the return type of a call of `peekCString'
  In a stmt of a 'do' block: ii <- (peekCString i)
  In the expression:
    do { ii <- (peekCString i);
       ss <- peekCString s;
       g <- newCString (isInfixOf ii ss);
       g }
```

If the compiler continued, it would give the same type error for the second `peekCString` line, and finally a

```
Couldn't match type `Bool' with `[Char]'
Expected type: String
  Actual type: Bool
In the first argument of `newCString', namely ...
```

for the wrongly typed argument of `newCString` (plus another `IO` - `Ptr` mismatch).

Answer (score 2):

You must use a monadic function as you are doing IO stuff:

```
grep :: CString -> CString -> IO CString
grep i s = do
    ii <- peekCString i
    ss <- peekCString s
    newCString (isInfixOf ii ss)
```

Also adapt your export clause:

```
foreign export ccall grep :: CString -> CString -> IO CString
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I wanted (except the newCString mistake I made, returning IO Bool would be fine). The ghc error seems misleading to me.